# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes' ? Keras seq2seq classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, classification, lstm

I have a problem with creating a Keras model. I found a simple encoder decoder and try to fix it like below:

```
   # some encoder code ... .... above is not shown here, where it is too obvious
    encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)

    encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

    decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
    decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(encoder_outputs[-1:], initial_state=encoder_states)
    decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

    model = Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs], outputs=decoder_outputs)
```

which will use the last encoder output as decoder input and only goes for a single output.

I wonder why it creates such a problem at:

```
model = Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs], outputs=decoder_outputs)
```

and creating message:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

How do I solve it? I tried to find similar questions' answers but I didn't get a good one to fix mine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `encoder_outputs[-1:]` would give you the last batch, not the last output of each batch which is `encoder_outputs[:,-1:]`.

Second, since you need to pass Keras Tensors to layers in Keras, you need to use a [`Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer to do the slicing:

```
last_input = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-1:])(encoder_inputs)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(last_input,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
```

Comment: well, sorry to not inform you  that the input type of decoder [does not include] batch size. Input shape is [sequence length x feature length]. So your guess that encoder_outputs[-1:] is the last batch is wrong. But anyways, Lambda seems working although I have to test a few things more. Once I am confident with it, I will come back and accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: @IsaacSim Oh, my dear! **It is impossible that the batch axis is not present in the tensors.** Either you have explicitly set the batch size using `batch_input_shape` or it is implicitly added by Keras itself.